# How to replicate sha256 hash example from CyberSource REST API documentation?

Tags: cryptography, sha256, cybersource

I am investigating the CyberSource REST API and want to test the JSON Web Token Authentication method as documented here: https://developer.cybersource.com/api/developer-guides/dita-gettingstarted/authentication/GenerateHeader/jwtTokenAuthentication.html

I am unable to replicate the sha256 hash of the JSON payload described in the JWT Payload/Claim Set section.

```
{
  "clientReferenceInformation" : {
    "code" : "TC50171_3"
  },
  "orderInformation" : {
    "amountDetails" : {
      "totalAmount" : "102.21",
      "currency" : "USD"
    }
  }
}
```

I've attempted to use the sha256sum command in binary and text format on a file containing the payload example. I've also attempted running this command on different permutations of this payload, such as without whitespace or newlines.

I expect to get the example hash of

`2b4fee10da8c5e1feaad32b014021e079fe4afcf06af223004af944011a7cb65c`

but instead get

`f710ef58876f83e36b80a83c8ec7da75c8c1640d77d598c470a3dd85ae1458d3` and other dissimilar hashes.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are not doing anything wrong. Hash functions have a [avalanche effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect), wherein any different bit in the input changes a lot the output hash. If the site's original example used a different encoding, or had a different order for the JSON elements, or even had more or less tabs, spaces, line breaks, or any other "trash" character, you'll have a hard time to find a fitting message for the  hash showed in the site.

Usually, cryptographic solutions use canonicalizations to avoid this kind of problem (different hash values for semantically equal messages). However, the [JWT specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) doesn't specify any type of canonicalization for JSON.

In short, I think you don't have to worry about this. Your JWT implementation will be correct as long you use a valid (correctly implemented) hash function.

Also, I noticed that the [JWT specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) doesn't specify a "Digest" field for the JWT payload. So, you may not even need to use this field. Unless CyberSource REST API makes it mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Since the alleged "example" hash contains 33 hex characters one can see that it is not a possible valid output of SHA256. So there is nothing you can do to make your example match theirs.

There is also a base64 example in that discussion, but it is also not valid base64. By adding an extra padding character '=' to the base64 it can be made valid, and decoding it reveals that it mostly matches the alleged SHA256 hash.

My guess is that the values on that page are just examples of what values look like to the human eye rather than test vectors you are supposed to match exactly.